# Difference between Set() and RaisePropertyChanged()

Tags: mvvm, prism, mvvm-light

I am reading this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx to learn mvvm light framework.
I download the source code Friend.cs.

My question is why some set method of different property are implemented differently.

For example, the setter for First name is, why I need 'ref' keyword for _firstName.

```
 Set(FirstNamePropertyName, ref _firstName, value);
```

And the setter for DateOfBirthString is "

```
RaisePropertyChanged(() => DateOfBirth);
```

When will the linq expression will be evaluated?

```
namespace MyFriends.Model
{
    [SimpleSerialize]
    public class Friend : ObservableObject
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="FirstName" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string FirstNamePropertyName = "FirstName";

        private string _firstName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the FirstName property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        [SimpleSerialize(FieldName = "first_name")]
        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _firstName;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(FirstNamePropertyName, ref _firstName, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="LastName" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string LastNamePropertyName = "LastName";

        private string _lastName;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the LastName property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        [SimpleSerialize(FieldName = "last_name")]
        public string LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return _lastName;
            }
            set
            {
                Set(LastNamePropertyName, ref _lastName, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="DateOfBirth" /> property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string DateOfBirthPropertyName = "DateOfBirth";

        private string _dateOfBirthString;

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets and gets the DateOfBirth property.
        /// Changes to that property's value raise the PropertyChanged event. 
        /// </summary>
        [SimpleSerialize(FieldName = "birthday")]
        public string DateOfBirthString
        {
            get
            {
                return _dateOfBirthString;
            }
            set
            {
                _dateOfBirthString = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => DateOfBirth);
            }
        }

        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_dateOfBirthString))
                {
                    return DateTime.MinValue;
                }

                return DateTime.ParseExact(DateOfBirthString, "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            set
            {
                _dateOfBirthString = value.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
        }

        private string _imageUrl;

        [SimpleSerialize(FieldName = "picture")]
        public string ImageUrl
        {
            get
            {
                return _imageUrl;
            }
            set
            {
                _imageUrl = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ImageUri);
            }
        }

        public Uri ImageUri
        {
            get
            {
                return new Uri(_imageUrl);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between those two methods is that the `Set` method replaces the old value of the `_firstName` field and then raises the `PropertyChanged` event, while the `RaisePropertyChanged` only raises the `PropertyChanged` event.

You'll want to use the `Set` method in most cases, since it helps to shorten property declarations by wrapping all that typically needs to be done within a property's setter in just one method:

1. It updates the value of the passed field and overwrites it with the content of `value`, and then
2. raises the `PropertyChanged` event to notify Views about this update.

The reason the field needs to be passed by reference (thus using `ref _firstName`) is that not the field's content is needed within the `Set` method, but the field itself is actually updated.

The `RaisePropertyChanged` method is useful when an update of one property does also affect additional properties. In this case, these properties' contents need to be updated manually, then the `RaisePropertyChanged` method can be called to inform Views about which properties have actually changed.

Answer (score 1):

One instance I found that Set(ref _prop, value)
doesn't work is when you need to resend an update or need to do a custom comparison. Set(ref _prop, value)
 will do a compare on the _prop and value for you but it may not be what you want. For some properties i may want to add some more conditions beyond just a comparison in which case I'll set the _prop = value manually and then raise the change right after;

But in most cases I use the Set(ref _prop, value)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an actual usage, where the `IsRunning` is the primary operation, but it also raises a change notification on the property `IsComplete` which is based on `IsRunning`. This way both properties send a notify without undo extra coding.

```
private bool _IsRunning;

public bool IsRunning
{
    get => _IsRunning;
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _IsRunning, value);
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsComplete");
    }
}

public bool IsComplete => !IsRunning;
```