# UWP - Is this bounded property running on UI Context?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, binding, xbind

I have a simple bool bound to a ProgressRing IsActive property. The property resides in a ViewModel base class. Here is the code:

```
<!--XAML-->
<ProgressRing
    x:Name="RestrictAppProgress"
    Margin="10"
    IsActive="{x:Bind _vm.ProgressRingActive, Mode=OneWay}" Width="30" Height="30"
    Foreground="#FF9333"/>
```

```
// ViewModel base class
private bool _progressRingActive;
public bool ProgressRingActive
{
    get => _progressRingActive;
    set
    {
        _progressRingActive = value;
        Set(() => ProgressRingActive, ref _progressRingActive, value);
    }
}

// ViewModel
public override async Task InitViewModel(ClassState classState)
{
    ProgressRingActive = true;

    _restrictModel = new RestrictAppModel();
    var success = await _restrictModel.LoadAppsFromServer().ConfigureAwait(true);

    ProgressRingActive = false;
}

// Code-behind OnNavigatedTo from Page class
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs restrictArgs)
{
    ...
    await _vm.InitViewModel(state.classState).ConfigureAwait(true);
}

// Model class method that makes an await call
public async Task<bool> LoadAppsFromServer()
{
    try
    {
        var appsListJson = await service.GetAppList(Settings.TeacherDistrictId).ConfigureAwait(true);
        ...
    }
    catch (ApiException ex)
    {
        ...
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

So, when the page loads and goes to `OnNavigatedTo`, my understanding is that we are still in the UI context. When we reach `await _vm.InitViewModel(state.classState).ConfigureAwait(true);` in `OnNavigatedTo`, my understanding is that because this call is awaited, InitViewModel does not take place in the UI Context, so when the bound property `ProgressRingActive` changes, the property change is not being fired on UI thread, so no change is made. Is this right?

I tried getting rid of the await call before `_vm.InitViewModel`, thinking that it would enter the method on the UI context, if I remove the await on `vm.InitViewModel` call, isn't `ProgressRingActive = true;` made on the UI context, then the call to `var success = await _restrictModel.LoadAppsFromServer().ConfigureAwait(true);` is marshalled on a different context, and once it returns we are back on the UI context, with `ProgressRingActive = false;` being made inside UI context? I am not 100% sure.

The only thing that has worked so far is calling `Bindings.Update()` at the end of the `OnNavigatedTo` method.

Comment: `Set(() => ProgressRingActive, ref _progressRingActive, value);` what is this doing? I believe it should be updating the backing source and then fire off `NotifyPropertyChanged` and more than likely you are not. The only reason it is working when you call `Bindings.Update()` is because you're forcing the binding update that something has changed. You are using `x:Bind` and when doing so, you still have to tell the backing property that it has changed.

Comment: Set() is a MvvmLight method that implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: It should look like `Set(ref _progressRingActive, value);`, the overload uses `CallerMemberName`... I don't know if it makes a difference but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what is was. So, I am using MvvmLight libs, and they provide a `Set(Expression<Func<T>>, ref T, value)` method that ["...replaces the old value of the backing field and then raises the PropertyChanged event..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293193/difference-between-set-and-raisepropertychanged). My mistake in the code example that I provided was that in my `ViewModelBase` class, I set the backing variable to the value, then called `Set(...)` which **WON'T** raise the property changed event, because the backing variable and `value` are equal. So the solution is to just remove the `_progressRingActive = value;` line. Now, when `Set(...)` is called, it will raise the property changed event, because the backing variable and `value` are not equal.

There was also a hint in the editor itself, the key words being **"if needed."**:
[image]

The correct code for the ViewModelBase:

```
// ViewModel base class
private bool _progressRingActive;
public bool ProgressRingActive
{
    get => _progressRingActive;
    set
    {
        Set(() => ProgressRingActive, ref _progressRingActive, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> InitViewModel does not take place in the UI Context, so when the bound
>   property ProgressRingActive changes, the property change is not being
>   fired on UI thread, so no change is made. Is this right?

As this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53463932/uwp-update-ui-from-async-worker) said, async/await does not directly say the awaited code will run on a different thread. When you do `await _vm.InitViewModel()`, the execution enters the InitViewModel method still on the UI thread and still waits. Then the `_restrictModel.LoadAppsFromServer()` method will actually run asynchronously on a different thread. Once LoadAppsFromServer() is completed, await will returns to the UI thread.

> The only thing that has worked so far is calling Bindings.Update() at
>   the end of the OnNavigatedTo method.

About ProgressRing doesn't disappear, it is because although the value of ProgressRingActive has changed, but you didn't notify the UI to change. So you need to add the `RaisePropertyChanged()` method to notify the UI.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private bool _progressRingActive;
    public bool ProgressRingActive
    {
        get => _progressRingActive;
        set
        {
            _progressRingActive = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    ......
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, it absolutely is, you need Dispatcher Access in order to update the UI, this includes properties your element binds to.

```
if (!CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess)
                        await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.Yield();
                    await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                    {
//update UI here
})
```